# How to stop JFace combo box from re sizing on a window re size?

Tags: java, combobox, swt, jface

I have a Java Eclipse RCP program in which I have a a long string inside a JFace combobox. Now when I am in the same view,The combobox attaches a scroll over it to show the full name. but as soon as I re size the window of the application, the combobox stretches itself to accommodate the lengthy string.

How do i make the combobox stay the same size. Like the size of it should remain fixed even after I resize the window. Here are two screen shots to demonstrate the issue.

P.S. I am using a comboViewer and inside it a comboBox.

[image: desired behaviour]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Layout are you using?

Comment: I am using GridData. `preferredResourceCombo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));`

Comment: You could try setting the `widthHint` of the `GridData`

Comment: After some research I found out I am using Grid Data too. Grid Data's constructor has following argments `int horizontalAlignment, int verticalAlignment, boolean grabExcessHorizontalSpace, boolean grabExcessVerticalSpace, int horizontalSpan, int verticalSpan` in which I set `grabExcessHorizontalSpace` to false. Still If I resize I get the same result. What else could I try??

Comment: Thanks a lot greg that worked... :)

Comment: @greg-449 Write a proper answer please. Comments are not made for eternity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `GridLayout` and `GridData` as your layout you can specify a value in the `widthHint` field to suggest the width for the Combo.

```
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);

data.widthHint = 100;

preferredResourceCombo.setLayoutData(data);
```

Using a fixed value like this might cause problems if the user uses a large font. So an alternative way of calculating the width is to use `Dialog.convertWidthInCharsToPixels`:

```
GC gc = new GC(control);
gc.setFont(control.getFont());
FontMetrics fontMetrics = gc.getFontMetrics();
gc.dispose();

data.widthHint = Dialog.convertWidthInCharsToPixels(fontMetrics, charCount);
```

If your code is in a `Dialog` you can simplify this to just:

```
data.widthHint = convertWidthInCharsToPixels(charCount);
```

Comment: upvote for the additional comment on the effect of font value.

Comment: could you have a look [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761761/how-to-get-tooltip-in-a-listviewer-in-jface)