# How to get ToolTip in a ListViewer in JFace?

Tags: java, swt, jface, treeviewer

[image]

This is a gridLayout in which the Available side is a Tree Viewer and The Selected side is a ListViewer. Now I have to get a toolTip on the right hand side. Which I am unable to get. I am working on a existing code base , so I am unable to figure out on which line did they add a tooltip + I did not find any keywords like tooltip or mouse Hover. Still how is this implemented. 
I am mentioning some code. I believe the answer should be somewhere here only.

```
 availableViewer = new TreeViewer(resultsComposite, SWT.BORDER | this.getStyle());
        availableViewer.setContentProvider(new ResAndResGroupTreeContentProvider());
        availableViewer.setLabelProvider(SelectionItemLabelProvider.getInstance());
        Tree availableResults = availableViewer.getTree();
        GridData availableResultsGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        availableResultsGridData.widthHint = LIST_WIDTH_HINT;
        availableResultsGridData.heightHint = LIST_HEIGHT_HINT;
        availableResults.setLayoutData(availableResultsGridData);
        availableViewer.getTree().addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e)
            {
                moveAvailableItemsToSelected();
            }
        });
```

This is the selectionViewer content.

```
  selectedViewer = new ListViewer(resultsComposite, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL| SWT.BORDER
            | this.getStyle());
    selectedViewer.setContentProvider(new ResAndResGroupTreeContentProvider());
    selectedViewer.setLabelProvider(new SelectionItemLabelProvider());
    org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List selectedResults = selectedViewer.getList();
    GridData selectedResultsGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    selectedResultsGridData.widthHint = LIST_WIDTH_HINT;
    selectedResultsGridData.heightHint = LIST_HEIGHT_HINT;
    selectedResults.setLayoutData(selectedResultsGridData);
    selectedViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event)
        {
            moveSelectedItemsToAvailable();
        }
    });
    selectedViewer.getList().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.character == SWT.CR)
            {
                moveSelectedItemsToAvailable();
            }
        }
    });
    selectedViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event)
        {
            updateButtonsEnabled();
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport` is the usual way but I don't see that here.

Comment: Could there be any other method, by which they could be doing it?

Comment: On some platforms the native tree control will show the whole of a long string as a tooltip automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListViewer`s underlying `List` widget cannot show different tooltips for each item.
You can assign a tooltip for the entire list like so

```java
listViewer.getList().setTooltipText( "..." );
```

But if you want a differnt tooltip per item you'll have to use a `TableViewer`.

What you see on the left side is the native Windows tooltip that appears if an item exceeds the horizontal space. The `Table` (on Windows) has the same behavior, thus you don't need to explicitly provide tooltips.

For a control that has a default tool tip, such as the `Tree` on Windows, setting the tooltip to `null` replaces the default, causing no tooltip to be shown.

Comment: but what we have used on the left hand side is a TreeViewer. How does it has an inherent property of windows?

Comment: [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTreeViewer.html) of tree viewer mentions nothing about this

Comment: @SarasArya This is a feature of the native tree control that SWT uses and varies between platforms (the Mac tree control also does this).